# Intel hex validation tools

Tags: validation, hex, intel

Are there any good validation tools for Intel hex files. Im looking for something that will validate checksums, as well as being able to identify and extract things like start address records?

Answer (score 0):

This one is tricky... Well in any case I'm sorry to say this but the best way to do it is to use a HEX editor and cross reference with things you know exists in the start or end address. So in other words the best way is to do it manually by hand. 
**UPDATE**
I may have something that you would find interesting http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX. At the bottom of the page is exactly what I believe you are looking for but I stay by my standpoint that validating it by hand is still the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following .NET library: [IntelHexFormatReader](https://github.com/christophediericx/IntelHexFormatReader) for this.

*(Disclaimer: I wrote the library).*

Validating a single line in the HEX file could look like this:

```
string hexRecordLine = ":100130003F0156702B5E712B722B732146013421C7";
IntelHexRecord record = HexFileLineParser.ParseLine(hexRecordLine);
Console.WriteLine(record.ByteCount);
Console.WriteLine(record.Address.ToString("X4"));
Console.WriteLine(record.RecordType.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(record.Bytes[5]);
Console.WriteLine(record.Bytes[9]);
Console.WriteLine(record.CheckSum);
```

Resulting in the following output:

```
16
0130
Data
94
43
199
```

The tools does exhaustive validation (check the unit tests in order to get an idea of what validations are in place) and also allows you to return a full "memory representation" for a full Intel Hex file.